# How to pass id from url parameter to another page by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating ecommerce site by php. In my home page when anyone click any category (like mobile) in shop page i wanna show those category wise product by getting the category id in shop page url. I wanna make this by using ajax and also when click any brand (like samsung) checkbox in shop page brand wise product will auto load by ajax.

I am able to show brand wise product when checkbox checked but i can't show category wise product because dont know how to pass category id by ajax and catch the id on shop page

***I have tried this way***

In shop page Ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    filter_data();
    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading"style=""></div>');
        var action='action';
        var brand=get_filter('brand');
        var id = <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>; // get id from page url
        $.ajax({
            url: 'action.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {action: action,brand: brand,id: id},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
//load by check the checkbox
    function get_filter(class_name) {
        var filter=[];
        $('.'+class_name+':checked').each(function() {
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });
        return filter;
    }
    $('.common_selector').click(function() {
        filter_data();
    });
});
</script>
```

show category and brand wise product

```
<?php
session_start();
include'core/db.php';
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $query="select * from product where cat=id "; // selecting category wise product by id which was sent from ajax but faild 
}
if (isset($_POST["brand"])) {
    $brand_filter = implode(',',$_POST['brand']);
    $query="select * from product where brand IN ('$brand_filter')";
    $dbquery=mysqli_query($db,$query);
    $count =mysqli_num_rows($dbquery);
    $output = '';
    if ($count > 0) {
        while ($bf=mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbquery))
        {
            $output.='<div class="col-md-3 ">
                        <div class="product">
                         <h3>'.$bf["title"].'</h3>
                         <img src="img/'. $bf['image'] .'" class="img-responsive" >
                            <p class="Price"><b>Price:</b>'.$bf["price"].' </p>
                            <a href="details.php?id='.$bf['id'].'" class="btn btn-success">
                                Details
                            </a>
                              <button id="product" pid='.$bf["id"].' class="btn btn-primary">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add Cart
                            </button>

                        </div>
                    </div>';
        }
    } else {
        $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

Since 6 month i am stuck on this project, if its solve then user side will be complete, So I humbly request for your help ....

Comment: are you getting any err

Comment: @Deepak No just category wise product not showing

Comment: is the ajax working?

Comment: @Deepak  working when i check the brand in checkbox then its showing brand wise product but now showing product when page load suppose to show category wise product.. is there any fault passing url id by ajax?

Comment: please add url in comment. I want to know what type of url you made

Comment: check my code now.please check if the id is passing or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  to get the values of id before passing it in your query

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include'core/db.php';
    if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
        $id=$_SESSION['id'];

        $query="select * from product where cat='$id' "; // selecting category wise product by id which was sent from ajax but faild 
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST["brand"])) {
        $brand_filter = implode(',',$_POST['brand']);
        $query="select * from product where brand IN ('$brand_filter')";
    }
        $dbquery=mysqli_query($db,$query);
        $count =mysqli_num_rows($dbquery);
        $output = '';
        if ($count > 0) {
            while ($bf=mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbquery))
            {
                $output.='<div class="col-md-3 ">
                            <div class="product">
                             <h3>'.$bf["title"].'</h3>
                             <img src="img/'. $bf['image'] .'" class="img-responsive" >
                                <p class="Price"><b>Price:</b>'.$bf["price"].' </p>
                                <a href="details.php?id='.$bf['id'].'" class="btn btn-success">
                                    Details
                                </a>
                                  <button id="product" pid='.$bf["id"].' class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add Cart
                                </button>

                            </div>
                        </div>';
            }
        } else {
            $output = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
        }
        echo $output;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190841/discussion-on-answer-by-deepak-how-to-pass-id-from-url-parameter-to-another-page).